# How do I stop php to direct to a blank page, and making a notification in html

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form in my html. After a user clicks submit, it redirects them to a blank page, which is the php document for the recaptcha check. How do I make it so it stays on the html page(So, it doesn't go to a blank page), and just displays a message saying "message sent", or if the recaptcha fails "reCAPTCHA failed. Please try again"?

HTML

```
<form name="form" method="post" class="contact" action="form.php">
        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
        <input class="text" name="name" type="text" />
        <br><br>

        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
        <input class="text" name="email" type="text" />
        <br><br>

        <label for="message">Message</label><br>
        <textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea>
        <br><br>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcFgRAUAAAAAEuBal0o_QvjBH-ZiGTKHJ25ZwaF"></div>
        <br><br>

        <input class="submit " name="submit" type="submit"  value="send"/>


    </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-           response'])):
    //your site secret key
    $secret = '';
    //get verify response data
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    if($responseData->success):
        //contact form submission code
        $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
        $email = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
        $message = !empty($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:'';

        $to = '';
        $subject = 'New contact form have been submitted';
        $htmlContent = "
            <h1>Contact request details</h1>
            <p><b>Name: </b>".$name."</p>
            <p><b>Email: </b>".$email."</p>
            <p><b>Message: </b>".$message."</p>
        ";
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
        //send email
        @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

        $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';

    else:
        $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
    endif;
else:
    $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
endif;
else:
$errMsg = '';
$succMsg = '';
endif;

?>
```

Comment: A: put everything in the same file or use ajax

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please clarify.

Comment: @COOKIE the OP wants to process a request to a recaptha service without the user leaving the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include html code in your PHP script.

Based on your code:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-           response'])):
    //your site secret key
    $secret = '';
    //get verify response data
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    if($responseData->success):
        //contact form submission code
        $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
        $email = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
        $message = !empty($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:'';

        $to = '';
        $subject = 'New contact form have been submitted';
        $htmlContent = "
            <h1>Contact request details</h1>
            <p><b>Name: </b>".$name."</p>
            <p><b>Email: </b>".$email."</p>
            <p><b>Message: </b>".$message."</p>
        ";
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
        //send email
        @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

        $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';

    else:
        $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
    endif;
else:
    $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
endif;
else:
?>
<form name="form" method="post" class="contact" action="form.php">
        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
        <input class="text" name="name" type="text" />
        <br><br>

        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
        <input class="text" name="email" type="text" />
        <br><br>

        <label for="message">Message</label><br>
        <textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea>
        <br><br>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcFgRAUAAAAAEuBal0o_QvjBH-ZiGTKHJ25ZwaF"></div>
        <br><br>

        <input class="submit " name="submit" type="submit"  value="send"/>


    </form>
<?php
$errMsg = '';
$succMsg = '';
endif;

?>
```

Don't forget to include the rest of your html code, links to stylesheets, etc.

Comment: Ohh ok. Do you want me to give the rest of the html?

Comment: Well, it's your code. The only thing you need to do in the PHP side is to show your success/error message with [echo](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.echo.php) for example.

Comment: But if I use echo, I think it shows the message on the blank page. What should I do to display the message on the html document?

Comment: You can't. The html page is static, you can't dynamically show messages. Not like this, actually. As Fred said, a solution would be to use an ajax call but perhaps it's a bit too difficult for now. You can have your whole html code on your php script, it's not a problem. Simply use <?php ?> when you want to write php code and not html. Hope it helps !

Comment: So, in the html. Instead of linking to a php page. Inside the action element. I put the php code?

Comment: Nope, do the opposite ! html documents don't recognize php code but php documents do recognize html and, obviously, php. So the idea is to set your classic html document and replace  your form by the code i copied. This page will replace your precedent html page. Don't forget to change the `action` path of your form, if needed.